# Regexp_extract BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How to extract cellphone number from the note like:

"`From: Anna Evteeva<br>To: +34-616-05-07-09 (Graeser & Partner deal (1))<br>Duration: 00:25 seconds<br>Recording: <a href="https://app.toky.co/business/recording/outbound/qlb23ikr9c7q790lq964" target="_blank">https://app.toky.co/business/recording/outbound/qlb23ikr9c7q790lq964</a>`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract):

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT('From: Anna Evteeva<br>To: +34-616-05-07-09 (Graeser & Partner deal (1))<br>Duration: 00:25 seconds<br>Recording: <a href="https://app.toky.co/business/recording/outbound/qlb23ikr9c7q790lq964" target="_blank">https://app.toky.co/business/recording/outbound/qlb23ikr9c7q790lq964</a>', r'\+\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
```

Modify `r'\+\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'` per your requirements.

Comment: what if country code varies? how to extract one digit or three digit code which is followed after "+"? @SergeyGeron

Comment: try `r'\+\d{1,3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}'`